# how to call a fragment from dialog box in android?

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

i want to know, how to call a fragment from dialog box click action in android. The dialog box is in another activity.

below is the dialog box section code

```
public static void Bookingconfirm(final Context _context, String title,String strMessage)
{
    final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(_context);

    Log.e("Point","1");
    dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.booking_success);
    dialog1.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialog1.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog1.findViewById(R.id.d_location);
    LinearLayout btnok = (LinearLayout) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.booking_ok);


    btnok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {   
            Log.e("Point","2"); 

            //i wanted the click to fragment here
            // parent class of fragment Home.java and fragment is booking.java


        }
    });


    dialog1.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Fragment fragment= booking.newInstance();
 Home mainActivity = (Home) context;
        FragmentManager manager = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "Frag");
        transaction.commit();
```

Try the above code from your dialog click Listener  ...Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try the below code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new booking());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Haroon and pradeep answer wont work.
you can pass FragmentManager to your dialog class like this:

```
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

 class TestDialog(val fragmentManager:FragmentManager) {

   fun show()
   {
      showFragmentButton.setOnClickListener{

       val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
       val fragment = PurchaseDetail()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "cashier_fragment")
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()

        }
   }
}
```

and in your fragment:

```
 TestDialog(getFragmentManager()).show()
```